# SharePoint: Media Player Custom Field Control

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to implement the Media Player custom field control described in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981226.aspx

I created a custom site column (of type Link) in a custom content type and followed all the instructions to deploy the solution into SharePoint and add the control to a Page Layout.

However, when I create a page based on a page layout that uses this field control, nothing is displayed in either Edit or View mode of the page.

I dug around in the SharePoint logs, and at the time the page is loaded, I see the following error in ULS:

Control template "MediaPlayerFieldControl" does not exist.

If you've implemented this control, did you have to implement anything other than what the article details? Pretty sure I don't need an ASCX here because the control is handling rendering the media player.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out ...

I had added the SafeControl entry manually at first to my web.config, and for some reason that didn't work. I'm now including it in manifest.xml like this:

```
<Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="MyControlAssembly.dll">
  <SafeControls>
    <SafeControl Assembly="MyControlAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=07085c2a3fb711ee" Namespace="MyControlAssembly" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
  </SafeControls>
</Assembly>
```

Not sure what the difference there was, but this did the trick

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2007 doesn't have byte-range requests. Doing a query for a large media file will take the entire blob from SQL and store it on the WFE. I'd be careful about how you implement this.

Comment: Good call Kevin, we're doing this for small files. Will definitely look into Windows streaming services when there's a requirement to stream larger files

Answer (score 0):

copy file MediaPlayerFieldControl.ascs  to path: " C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES "